# Button hover animation with anime.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, anime.js

First, sorry about my english :) I need some help, because I'm really beginner in javascript. I use the https://animejs.com/ library, and I want to create button hover animation for that. The problem is that: inside a button there is an SVG (arrow), and I would like to animating that when the mouseenter over the button. My first problem that any number of buttons inside the page, but I use jquery bind() function, it seems a good way to do this. But the second, and the main problem: if I hover on the button, and then I leave the button, and then quckliy hover again this button, the animation start the first position. But I don't want this untill the first hover animation it still takes on the SVG arrow is animating. I hope I have written it down clearly :)

The problem code is that: https://codepen.io/boximoxi/pen/mvWwog
You see my concern if you drag the mouse over the button.

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var buttonEl = $('.btn-stroke-draw');

  buttonEl.bind({
    mouseenter: function(event) {
      var target = $(event.target).find('.arrow');
      function enterButton() {
        var buttonAnimation = anime({
          targets: target[0],
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'cubicBezier(.5, .05, .1, .3)',
          autoplay: true,
          translateY: [
            {
              duration: 200,
              value: '-4px',
            },
            {
              duration: 150,
              value: '0',
            },
            {
              duration: 200,
              value: '-4px',
            },
            {
              duration: 150,
              value: '0',
            },
            {
              duration: 200,
              value: '-4px',
            },
            {
              duration: 150,
              value: '0',
            }
          ]
        });
      }
      enterButton();
    }
  });
});
```

And I want something like that, but only the hovered button: https://codepen.io/boximoxi/pen/yZMXdM
This example show you, if you drag the mouse hover the button, the arrow animation playing from beginning to end, but all arrow animating inside the page.

Anyone can help me this, I would be very grateful for it :)

Answer (score 0):

I only understand the problem that the animation restart on hover repeatedly even while its in a middle of its animation

this is normal behavior cuz when you hover the button a selector named :hover being added to your class and its restarting the animation thats how css animation works

you should try to use javascript to prevent it you can maybe add a class on mouseEnter
and then set timeout to the time of the animation to prevent the mouseEnter

there are more ways but the page short to specify them all